# XML key constraint does not work with element that uses ref

Tags: xml, xpath, key, xsd, xml-validation

So basically I have the problem that the key constraint I require does not get applied properly when I use element references. So for example something like this:

```
<xs:element ref="B" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

note that the name of elements, attributes, namespaces and so one are just samples, they later on they will have logical names

So  have an XML schema that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" xmlns="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">  

    <xs:element name="B">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="c" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="d" type="xs:hexBinary" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="A" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="B" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="bk">
            <xs:selector xpath="A/B"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@c"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

which gets applied to the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<A xmlns="test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="test schema.xsd">
    <B c="test0" d="0011"/>
    <B c="test1" d="2233"/>
    <B c="test1" d="4455"/>
</A>
```

As you can see the key constraint is bascially invalid, as there are two Bs with the same c (test1 in this case). However when validated against the schema (using visual studio 2012), this not recognise this as an error.

However when I change the XML schema to this, it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" xmlns="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">  
    <xs:element name="A" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="B" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="c" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="d" type="xs:hexBinary" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="bk">
            <xs:selector xpath="A/B"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@c"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So basically the element is included in A without a reference, so I assume that it has something to do with the xpath attribute of the selector of the key.

question is, how do I get this to work with a element reference, since I would like to be able to use the element reference for more complex xml structures.

EDIT:

So it seems the solution with the targetnamespace as correct after all, I just had to use it correctly one the . The following now works and indicates that the xml file is invalid:

the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">  

    <xs:element name="B">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="c" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="d" type="xs:hexBinary" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="A" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="tns:B" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="bk">
            <xs:selector xpath="tns:B"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@c"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

the xml file also used the namespace as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tns:A xmlns:tns="test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="test test.xsd">
    <tns:B c="a" d="0011"/>
    <tns:B c="b" d="2233"/>
    <tns:B c="a" d="4455"/>
</tns:A>
```

Comment: This may be a scope issue. Have you tried to move your key definition to a larger scope, e.g. as the first child tag of your `<schema>` tag?

Comment: well its already in the A tag, which is the only element in the xml file. So I cant really go up anymore, in terms of scope.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256101%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. In this example there is also a target namespace and the XPath expressions use this namespace explicitly which would make your XPath `test:A/test:B`.

Comment: well I tried that one as well (I added tns as the namespace), but it did not work either. I also used this only [validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.Upxw5OKE7Qs), since visual studio began to throw some random warning at me, after editing the schema file for some time, that were not really there.

Comment: looks like you were right after all, I just had to add the namespace to the ref as well. could you post an answer to his question so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying XPath elements of keys and references the namespace of the target XML will have to be included. Using the namespace `tns` of your example schema the XPath expression of the key definition will have to be changed to

```
<xs:selector xpath="tns:A/tns:B"/>
```

Likewise, the XPath expression of the reference definition will have to be changed to

```
<xs:element ref="tns:B" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```